# Problems passing NSString as argument in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring, nsbundle

Here is the context of my problem. First there is a thread that gets started:

```
-(void)run_thread: (NSObject* )file_path_NSObject
{
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

NSString *local_recordFilePath_NSString = (NSString *)file_path_NSObject;

NSLog(@"run thread : path   %@     ", local_recordFilePath_NSString);

printf("Running Thread...\n");

runAllAudioRoutines(local_recordFilePath_NSString);

// more code....
```

Everything above prints correctly to the console. Then there is the method that gets called:

```
void runAllAudioRoutines(NSString *file)

{

NSLog(@"running All Audio Routines method...\n");

NSString *truncatedFilePath = [file stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"LoopExtended.wav"
                                                                withString:@"recordedFile.wav"];

NSLog(@"FILE for  !!!! -->  %@",truncatedFilePath);

const char *location  = [truncatedFilePath UTF8String];
const char *write_location = [file UTF8String];

int *vocal_data = read_wav(location, &size_vocal); 

// more code....
```

The strange thing is that *none* of the NSLogs print ***at all***. Nothing. Nada. Zip. And then the app crashes when it tries to pass the location to the read wav method (presumably because there is something wrong with the string).

This all started to happen when I switched from using NSTemporaryDirectory to NSBundle, but I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it. Any advice?

I've taken a Joetjah's suggestion and started using instead:

```
[self runAllAudioRoutines:local_recordFilePath_NSString];
     -(void)runAllAudioRoutines:(NSString*) file
```

and now I get this:[image]

Second run with 2nd suggestion from Joetjah[image]

Comment: It would be quite useful to be able to see the call stack and error your are getting in your console.

Comment: @Eric Brotto: I'd like to see the crash log as well. I guess changing the line to `[self runAllAdioRoutines:local_recordFilePath_NSString];` and the void-line to `-(void) runAllAudioRoutines:(NSString*) file {` doesn't work? Just to check ^^

Comment: I'm not getting any error or call stack in the console. Unless it is elsewhere(?)

Comment: @Eric Brotto: good thing to see there is some progress (?) in it. At what line does the crash occur? Log seems to indicate the runAllAudioRoutines method gains a nil object, but I see something else. Your log doesn't say `run thread : path %@` Try to allocate the string with: `NSString *local_recordFilePath_NSString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:file_path_NSObject];` instead of your line `NSString *local_recordFilePath_NSString = (NSString *)file_path_NSObject;` and see if it has any effect?

Comment: @Joetjah, Sorry, but run thread does get called. I just didn't include it in the photo. I took your suggestion anyway. Screen shot is included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message you are getting says that `SpeakHereController` doesn't implement the method `runAllAudioRoutines:`.

Did you call `runAllAudioRoutines:` on the right object?

**Expanding:** Objective-C is a dynamic language. You can call any method on any object, but if the object doesn't implement the method, the app will crash, with the message:

> "unrecognized selector sent to instance ..."

C++ is a static languages. If you try to call a function that isn't defined for an object, it won't compile. In Objective-C, it will compile, but you get the error during runtime. This is what's happening to you.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. Could you expand?